# Eclipse not recognizing json-simple

Tags: java, json, eclipse, json-simple

When I try to run `import org.json.simple.JSONObject;`, I get an error saying

> the type org.json.simple.JSONObject is not accessible

If I try to change it to `import org.json.simple.*;`, I still get an error saying the package is not accessible. I have included json-simple-1.1.1.jar in my classpath.

json-simple in my classpath

[image]

I also tried to make my project a Maven project and add it as a dependency there, but it was of no use.

The last comment in [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1103894/) mentions that compiling using Java 13 helped him, so I changed my execution environment to JavaSE-13, but that did not solve the issue either.

Comment: As your jar file is in C drive. Might be a chance that it may have permission only for the Administrator. Can you try with changing location or you can put it in lib folder as well.

Comment: @pratikpatel tried running Eclipse as administrator to fix that, no success. Also, I haven't fragmented my drive, so I just have C.

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file delete it (or move the JAR from the classpath to the modulepath and in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...` statement).

Comment: Running Eclipse as administrator is a pretty bad idea. The error says that you are doing something wrong, not that something is wrong with Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger deleting `module-info.java` worked. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: @howlger also, thanks for the tip. Won't be running it as admin from now.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @howlger, deleting the `module-info.java` file worked.